# Running Great Expectations in AWS Athena

Tags: sqlalchemy, great-expectations, pyathena

Hello I need some help on running GX on AWS Athena.

Here is my config

```py
conn_str = f"awsathena+rest://:@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}"
data = context.sources.add_sql(
    name="props", connection_string=conn_str
)
context.add_or_update_expectation_suite("data_expectation_suite")
data_asset = data.add_table_asset(name="properties", table_name="existing_prop_boundaries")
batch_req = data_asset.build_batch_request()
validator = context.get_validator(
    batch_request=batch_req,
    expectation_suite_name="data_expectation_suite",
)
validator.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null(column="id")
```

This Expectation works

But if I use

```py
conn_str = f"awsathena+rest://:@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}"
data = context.sources.add_sql(
    name="props_q", connection_string=conn_str
)
context.add_or_update_expectation_suite("data_q_expectation_suite")
data_asset = data.add_query_asset(name="properties_q", query="SELECT * FROM props WHERE id=1128")
batch_req = data_asset.build_batch_request()
validator = context.get_validator(
    batch_request=batch_req,
    expectation_suite_name="data_q_expectation_suite",
)
validator.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null(column="id")
```

Then it gives an error

```
MetricResolutionError: Textual SQL expression '%(5634247264 anon)s' should be explicitly declared as text('%(5634247264 anon)s')
```

Can anyone help regarding this

Comment: Does `from sqlalchemy import text;...;query=text("SELECT * FROM props WHERE id=1128")` work?

Comment: No query can only be string type.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy do you have installed?